# Dagger2 Subcomponent error - where have to annotate method ArrayAdapter

Tags: android, dagger-2, dagger

I use dagger2 demo by https://guides.codepath.com/android/Dependency-Injection-with-Dagger-2. I want to use subcomponent for ArrayAdapter injection in DemoDaggerSubActivity.java.

my Application.java

```
@Override public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    mApplicationComponent = DaggerApplicationComponent.builder()
            .applicationModule(new ApplicationModule(this))
            .build();
}


public ApplicationComponent getApplicationComponent() {
    return mApplicationComponent;
}
```

my MyActivityModule.java

```
@Module
public class MyActivityModule {
private final DemoDaggerSubActivity activity;

// must be instantiated with an activity
public MyActivityModule(DemoDaggerSubActivity activity) { this.activity = activity; }

@Provides
@MyActivityScope
@Named("my_list")
public ArrayAdapter providesMyListAdapter() {
    return new ArrayAdapter<String>(activity, android.R.layout.activity_list_item);
}

}
```

my MyActivitySubComponent.java

```
@MyActivityScope
@Subcomponent(modules={ MyActivityModule.class })
public interface MyActivitySubComponent {
    @Named("my_list") ArrayAdapter myListAdapter();
}
```

my ApplicationComponent.java

```
@Singleton
@Component( modules = {ApplicationModule.class} )
public interface ApplicationComponent {
void inject(DemoDaggerSubActivity activity);

// factory method to instantiate the subcomponent defined here (passing in the module instance)
MyActivitySubComponent newMyActivitySubcomponent(MyActivityModule activityModule);

}
```

my DemoDaggerSubActivity.java

```
@Inject @Named("my_list")
ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

((AttendanceApplication) getApplication()).getApplicationComponent().newMyActivitySubcomponent(new MyActivityModule(this)).inject(this);

}
```

After project rebuild I have got error

[image]

Where have I to annotate method ArrayAdapter ?

Comment: You've missed to add subcomponent into the graph hence the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have to remove inject method from ApplicationComponent.java and put it to  MyActivitySubComponent.java

new MyActivitySubComponent.java

```
@MyActivityScope
@Subcomponent(modules={ MyActivityModule.class })
public interface MyActivitySubComponent {

    void inject(DemoDaggerSubActivity activity);

    @Named("my_list") ArrayAdapter myListAdapter();
}
```

new ApplicationComponent.java

```
@Singleton
@Component( modules = {ApplicationModule.class} )
public interface ApplicationComponent {

    // factory method to instantiate the subcomponent defined here (passing in the module instance)
    MyActivitySubComponent newMyActivitySubcomponent(MyActivityModule activityModule);

}
```